# How to split/substring as given string in below format using java

Tags: java

i want to substring or split into List of Objects of number & description using java or java 8/9

```
"9 music recordings; Music files to download. 38 Providing access to music databases and to MP3 websites. 41 Organization of live musical events; Music publishing services; conducting music events; composing music for others; live entertainment production; live performances by musical bands; musical performances; music production; composing music; Operating a music recording studio."
```

The desired result is

```
List(0) object: number = 9 ,description = music recordings; Music files to download. 
List(1) object: number = 38 ,description = Providing access to music databases and to MP3 websites.
List(2) object: number = 41 ,description = Organization of live musical events; Music publishing services; conducting music events; composing music for others; live entertainment production; live performances by musical bands; musical performances; music production; composing music; Operating a music recording studio.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `String.split()` method with `"\\."` as your input. This will split the whole string into an array of strings. Then you can split on the first space.

Example:

Assuming the object you're trying to create is called `A`

```java
class A {
    public A(int num, String description);
}
```

then you can do:

```java
String str = ...
String[] strings = str.split("\."); // the \\ is so the regex engine doesn't think it's a wildcard character
for (String elem : strings) {
    elements = elem.split(" ", 2); // the 2 is so that it only splits into two strings on the first space
    int number = Integer.valueOf(elements[0]);
    A object = A(number, elements[1]); // do what you want with the object, add it to an array, whatever
}
```